# What does "new[]" mean with ReactiveCommand C# and how does this code execute?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactive

I am creating an application using Firebase Firestore and Plugin.CloudFirestore for Xamarin Forms based off of the Sample Project posted on the plugin's GitHub (link:
https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.CloudFirestore).

I am trying to learn how to write Async Reactive Commands based off of how they are written in the sample project but I'm having a really hard time reverse engineering this code.

```
            UpdateCommand = new[] {
                _todoItem.Select(x => x == null),
                Name.Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            }.CombineLatestValuesAreAllFalse()
             .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
             .ToAsyncReactiveCommand();

            UpdateCommand.Subscribe(async () =>
            {
                var todoItem = _todoItem.Value;
                todoItem.Name = Name.Value;
                todoItem.Notes = Notes.Value;

                _ = CrossCloudFirestore.Current.Instance.Document($"{TodoItem.CollectionPath}/{todoItem.Id}")
                    .UpdateAsync(todoItem)
                    .ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t.Exception);
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

                await navigationService.GoBackAsync();
            });
```

This code snippet is from the "TodoItemDetailPageViewModel.cs" file within the sample project if you would like more context.

The code above updates the field values of the document that is selected from the main page via the Firestore API. The code is working but I don't have any idea what the above code means and how the command works. Could someone break it down for me and explain what is going on? I am sure someone else could benefit as well.

Thanks

Comment: `new[]` creates a new C# array.  It's basic C#

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the contribution! This definitely helps to point me in the right direction however, this doesn't completely answer my question. Lol! What is the reason for creating the array? Why use system.linq to select null values?  What reason does the array need to execute the CombineLatestValuesAreAllFalse() or the ObserveOn() methods? Etc.